# Select com comportamento diferente no celular

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

Estou fazendo um script (não sei se é a melhor maneira, sou iniciante).

**Comportamento do script:**
O comportamento do script é o seguinte: Existe um select perguntando quantas pizzas você quer, ao responder eu libero o select perguntando se você quer borda recheada, se a resposta for sim, faço aparecer os selects com as opções de borda (sempre vai aparecer a mesma quantidade - máximo 5 - com base no número de pizzas do primeiro select).

Então faço praticamente a mesma mesma coisa para refrigerante, pergunto se a pessoa quer refrigerante, a quantidade e então aparecem as escolhas.

**O problema:**

Apenas no mobile e no select de refrigerante, para aparecem as opções de refrigerantes com base no número de refrigerantes, eu tenho que selecionar a opção e clicar novamente no campo de seleção para o comportamento correto acontecer. No desktop esse comportamento não acontece, ao clicar uma vez o script já funciona.

Como o Script ficou grande coloquei ele completo no Codepen: https://codepen.io/gustavo-bove/pen/xxZKrbj

```
    $("#refriQuestion").click(function () {

    if ($("#refriQuestion option:selected").val() == '1')
    {
        $("#refrisChoose1").show();
        $("#refrisChoose2").hide();
        $("#refrisChoose3").hide();
        $("#refrisChoose4").hide();
        $("#refrisChoose5").hide();

    }

    if ($("#refriQuestion option:selected").val() == '2')
    {
        $("#refrisChoose1").show();
        $("#refrisChoose2").show();

        $("#refrisChoose3").hide();
        $("#refrisChoose4").hide();
        $("#refrisChoose5").hide();


    }

    if ($("#refriQuestion option:selected").val() == '3')
    {
        $("#refrisChoose1").show();
        $("#refrisChoose2").show();
        $("#refrisChoose3").show();
        $("#refrisChoose4").hide();
        $("#refrisChoose5").hide();
    }


    if ($("#refriQuestion option:selected").val() == '4')
    {
        $("#refrisChoose1").show();
        $("#refrisChoose2").show();
        $("#refrisChoose3").show();
        $("#refrisChoose4").show();

        $("#refrisChoose5").hide();

    }

    if ($("#refriQuestion option:selected").val() == '5')
    {
        $("#refrisChoose1").show();
        $("#refrisChoose2").show();
        $("#refrisChoose3").show();
        $("#refrisChoose4").show();
        $("#refrisChoose5").show();

    }

});

$("#refrisChoose1").click(function ()
{

    if ($("#refrisChoose1 option:selected").val() == '1')
    {
        refriSelected1 = fanta;
        calcular();

    }

    if ($("#refrisChoose1 option:selected").val() == '2')
    {
        refriSelected1 = fanta_uva;
        calcular();
    }

    if ($("#refrisChoose1 option:selected").val() == '3')
    {
        refriSelected1 = soda;
        calcular();

    }

    if ($("#refrisChoose1 option:selected").val() == '4')
    {
        refriSelected1 = pepsi;
        calcular();
    }

    if ($("#refrisChoose1 option:selected").val() == '5')
    {
        refriSelected1 = guarana;
        calcular();

    }

});


$("#refrisChoose2").click(function ()
{

    if ($("#refrisChoose2 option:selected").val() == '1')
    {
        refriSelected2 = fanta;
        calcular();

    }

    if ($("#refrisChoose2 option:selected").val() == '2')
    {
        refriSelected2 = fanta_uva;
        calcular();

    }

    if ($("#refrisChoose2 option:selected").val() == '3')
    {
        refriSelected2 = soda;
        calcular();

    }

    if ($("#refrisChoose2 option:selected").val() == '4')
    {
        refriSelected2 = pepsi;
        calcular();

    }

    if ($("#refrisChoose2 option:selected").val() == '5')
    {
        refriSelected2 = guarana;
        calcular();

    }

});


$("#refrisChoose3").click(function ()
{

    if ($("#refrisChoose3 option:selected").val() == '1')
    {
        refriSelected3 = fanta;
        calcular();

    }

    if ($("#refrisChoose3 option:selected").val() == '2')
    {
        refriSelected3 = fanta_uva;
        calcular();

    }

    if ($("#refrisChoose3 option:selected").val() == '3')
    {
        refriSelected3 = soda;
        calcular();

    }

    if ($("#refrisChoose3 option:selected").val() == '4')
    {
        refriSelected3 = pepsi;
        calcular();
    }

    if ($("#refrisChoose3 option:selected").val() == '5')
    {
        refriSelected3 = guarana;
        calcular();

    }

});

$("#refrisChoose4").click(function ()
{

    if ($("#refrisChoose4 option:selected").val() == '1')
    {
        refriSelected4 = fanta;
        calcular();

    }

    if ($("#refrisChoose4 option:selected").val() == '2')
    {
        refriSelected4 = fanta_uva;
        calcular();


    }

    if ($("#refrisChoose4 option:selected").val() == '3')
    {
        refriSelected4 = soda;
        calcular();

    }

    if ($("#refrisChoose4 option:selected").val() == '4')
    {
        refriSelected4 = pepsi;
        calcular();

    }

    if ($("#refrisChoose4 option:selected").val() == '5')
    {
        refriSelected4 = guarana;
        calcular();
    }

});


$("#refrisChoose5").click(function ()
{

    if ($("#refrisChoose5 option:selected").val() == '1')
    {
        refriSelected5 = fanta;
        calcular();

    }

    if ($("#refrisChoose5 option:selected").val() == '2')
    {
        refriSelected5 = fanta_uva;
        calcular();

    }

    if ($("#refrisChoose5 option:selected").val() == '3')
    {
        refriSelected5 = soda;
        calcular();

    }

    if ($("#refrisChoose5 option:selected").val() == '4')
    {
        refriSelected5 = pepsi;
        calcular();

    }

    if ($("#refrisChoose5 option:selected").val() == '5')
    {
        refriSelected5 = guarana;
        calcular();

    }

});
```

Comportamento correto no Desktop:

[image: Comportamento correto no desktop]

[image: Comportamento incorreto no mobile]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O celular pode estar processando o elemento select de forma que o clique está além do DOM, tente

Troquar

```
   $("#refriQuestion").click(function () {
```

Por

```
 $("#refriQuestion").change(function () {
```

Assim, vinculando o event handler ao select e não na escolha.

https://api.jquery.com/change/
https://api.jquery.com/on/ (para `.on("change", function() {})`

Comment: Era exatamente isso. Muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Imagina, nozes !